# Heating tape that has leads like picture below

Tags: electrical-engineering, heating-systems, heat-treatment

Does anyone know where I can find Heating tape that has these same leads or know what they are called? It is meant to be plugged into the second picture attatched.[image]  [image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When searching for 1100 watt heating tape, a number of returns match almost exactly the image you've provided. A few of the manufacturers provide NEMA separable molded plugs and also offer bare leads. The bare leads would be useful in this case, as you can add your own 90° banana plugs.

[image: right angle enclosed banana plug]

To locate the correct plug, I used "right angle enclosed banana plug" as the search term. The image and source information came from [Zoro](https://www.zoro.com/zoro-select-banana-plug-right-angle-1000vac-red-5txc0/i/G1470156/feature-product?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIrMzDg5b_5wIViMDICh1c_wWLEAQYAiABEgIGnPD_BwE) online. I had better returns using shrouded in place of enclosed. Many sources. Be sure to check the current draw for the tape you'll use and the connector you'll select.